# Phoenix - No Suitable Driver Found jdbc:phoenix:localhost after Switching Project from Maven to Gradle

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle, apache-phoenix

I changed my spring-boot project from Maven to Gradle. Everything works well with Maven, but if I switch the project to Gradle, errors are occurring interestingly.

Full error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at ba.autisform.resource.dao.AdminDAO.saveUser(AdminDAO.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at ba.autisform.resource.dao.AdminDAO.checkUser(AdminDAO.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Gradle hadoop & phoenix dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-hadoop', version:'2.5.0.RELEASE'
    compile(group: 'org.apache.phoenix', name: 'phoenix-core', version:'4.10.0-HBase-1.1') {
        exclude(module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
        exclude(module: 'log4j')
        exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(module: 'servlet-api-2.5')
        exclude(module: '*')
    }
```

Application failed due to multiple loggings so I excluded `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j` from phoenix dependency.

Application failed due to `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED` field which was thrown by `org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext`  so I excluded `servlet-api`, `servlet-api-2.5` and `*`.

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0-HBase-1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the reason that weird errors are occurring after switching the project to Gradle?

Comment: You only posted a small part of the `build.gradle` and `pom.xml`. You need to compare `mvn dependency:tree` output with whatever is the Gradle equivalent to figure out what are the runtime dependencies. Also you should check how are you starting the application, maybe the classpath options were not migrated from Gradle.